# Cake\ORM\TableRegistry not working

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I am trying to use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry in my code. Composer is successfully installed but the code is showing this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ORM\vendor\cakephp\datasource\EntityTrait.php on line 528
```

Where is the issue?
I am using OS windows with php version 5.4.7

Code

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
ConnectionManager::config('default', [
    'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
    'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
    'database' => 'test',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'cacheMetaData' => false // If set to `true` you need to install the optional "cakephp/cache" package.
]);


$articles = TableRegistry::get('student');
foreach ($articles->find() as $article) {
    echo $article->name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Parse error: ... in ... datasource\EntityTrait.php on line 528

The [code on that line](https://github.com/cakephp/datasource/blob/master/EntityTrait.php#L528) is:

```
$class = static::class;
```

This is not an error caused by your usage of the vendor code - php *can't parse the file*.

## The version of php is too old

Whilst [the composer file for the datasource](https://github.com/cakephp/datasource/blob/master/composer.json) repo has no php requirements, the [composer file for cakephp/cakephp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/composer.json#L21), which that repo is built from, does:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
```

In this case the problem is that the code makes use of [features introduced in 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class), namely:

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name
>   resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name
>   of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class. This is particularly
>   useful with namespaced classes.
>
> Example #9 Class name resolution
>
> ```
> <?php
> namespace NS {
>     class ClassName {
>     }
>
>     echo ClassName::class;
> }
> ?>
> ```

Since the version of php in the question is 5.4.7 it does not have this feature and the code is treated as a parse error.

The simplest solution is to upgrade php to meet the version requirement of CakePHP. [Note that 5.4 is no longer supported](http://php.net/supported-versions.php):

[image: 5.4 is EOL, 5.5 is approaching EOL]

Comment: six
But when i tried to upgrade to 5.5. i am getting error that "php.exe is not a valid win32 application" .

Comment: six
What's the solution to the error described in last message then ?

Comment: ed stop using windows :)? Sorry, I don't use (or advocate using) windows, but problems upgrading aren't directly related to this question.

Comment: six
ypu meant to say that there is no any solution to this problem except changing OS?

Comment: There are always alternatives. CakePHP 3.2.0 [requires 5.5](http://bakery.cakephp.org/2016/01/29/cakephp_320_released.html), therefore you could use the [last 3.1.x release](https://github.com/cakephp/datasource/releases/tag/3.1.13), although that required 5.4.16 - which you also don't meet but things _probably_ work. Using an obsolete version of php is going to cause you ongoing problems, sooner or later you'll need to address that.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide Sounds like you are either using Windows XP, which isn't supported anymore as of PHP 5.5, or you're using the 64-Bit PHP binaries on a 32-Bit OS. In any case your environment seems a little outdated. But as AD7six said, that's out of scope of your initial question.